# VBA + Leap Motion + Dll

Tags: vba, leap-motion

Im an amateur VBA programer, and I need some help.
I need get VBA to work with Leap Motion Controler API (I want it to do simple controls) , but I dont have idea how.

I tried add references to Leap.dll, but got error ("Can't add a reference to the specified file ").

When I try to declare DLL [Declare Sub Leap Lib "D:\x64\Leap.dll" (ByRef FileName_ As String)], its not working (VBA does not see Leap API classes).

Thx for help.

Comment: I have no idea about leap motion but when you say it does not see it do you mean there is no intellisense for it? Intellisense will only show for a dll if you reference it for the project through tools>references (amongst other criteria). Also what language is the dll in? Just because it is a .dll does not mean that VBA can actually utilise any types within it. They will have to go via COM, which requires the DLL to expose types for COM interop -> check the .dll is set up for this. Again, this issue will be .dll specific and I have no experience of leap-motion and what it is.

Comment: Leap Motion doesn't support VBA, is C# an alternative solution?

Comment: Thx for help. Yes Leap do not support VBA. I try to walkaround with using dll.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to use a [C# DLL](https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/csharp/devguide/Sample_Tutorial.html) with VBA. Like what @Cor_Blimey said you will need to get the C# SDK source code then try to recompile it and [expose for COM](http://www.geeksengine.com/article/create-dll.html). I'm not sure that source is even available (I don't see it on GitHub).

Another approach would be to stick with the C# code and call it from VBA (this is what I would do). This is fairly straightforward but does require Visual Studio Professional (~$500) and you can learn about it here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608613.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a nodeJS server to access it through network instead of direct access, you can even access it from other devices where is not connect it.